# How to handle HTTP authentication for web app which will be accessed by other third party applications only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, authentication, http-headers, http-token-authentication

I am building a rails application which has both API and UI, I have implemented HTTP token authentication (header) for API and want to continue with same for web app as well if possible.

I am saving the user token in `session[:token]` and using `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` method for authentication.
The application_controller has the before filter and all other controllers are inherited hence HTTP header token is required for every endpoint in API and every page in the web app.

API is working fine because the partner application sends token every time  to access endpoints but in case of web app we are getting token for the first time (when the user gets redirected from the partner app) and control gets transferred to our app. Then we need a way to send HTTP header token for every route/page inside the rails app. Please suggest me a way to do that, or a completely different approach if this seems so complex.

Edit:

```
def authenticate_user 
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options| 
    user_id = Setting.long_decode_id(token) 
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id) 
    if (user.present?) 
      session[:api_current_user] = user.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if using a header token is the most straightforward approach in a web application, is there a reason you want to do it this way? You would need to be injecting the token into every request the user makes since their browser generally wouldn't do it for them.

Instead, why not use the token on the first visit (if that's the way you want to control access) but after that first entry set a session flag to skip that before filter until the session expires?

Alternatively there are a few great authentication gems out there, you could use one of those ([devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for example)

Comment: Hey Matt, Thanks for the answer. I agree, header token is not the best way to do this. But we have to this way for current project for some reasons (Not technical). I would like to try out the other suggestion of your's (session). Can you please help me with that (I am new to rails). Adding some code to the question, please check

Comment: def authenticate_user
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
  user_id = Setting.long_decode_id(token)
  user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
   if (user.present?)
    session[:api_current_user] = user.id

Comment: Hi @PrasadPilla, that code looks great - I have added it to your question for you as it is easier to follow when formatted. Does it work or cause problems? It looks like the right approach to me so long as you are then using the session variable in your before filter to bypass checks for subsequent requests.

Comment: Hey Matt, i have a filter  to make every request  go through the authentication method... before :authenticate_user. But i am a bit confused how to skip that when a user session is stored.